# Segmentation fault during IRkernel installation in R: 'memory not mapped'

Tags: r, installation, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, failed-installation

I am trying to install IRkernel to use R in jupyter notebooks. I fired up R at the terminal and typed:

```
> devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
```

and got:

```
Downloading GitHub repo IRkernel/IRkernel@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/IRkernel/IRkernel/zipball/master
Installing IRkernel
trying URL 'https://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/src/contrib/digest_0.6.15.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 122095 bytes (119 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 119 KB

Installing digest

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
 4: namespaceImport(ns, loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),     versionCheck = vI[[i]]), from = package)
 5: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
 6: namespaceImport(ns, loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),     versionCheck = vI[[i]]), from = package)
 7: loadNamespace(name)
 8: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 9: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
10: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
11: tryCatch(loadNamespace(name), error = function(e) stop(e))
12: getNamespace(ns)
13: asNamespace(pkg)
14: get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE)
15: evaluate:::default_output_handler
```

...

```
41: update(pkg, ..., Ncpus = threads, quiet = quiet, upgrade = upgrade)
42: install_deps(pkg, dependencies = initial_deps, upgrade = upgrade_dependencies,     threads = threads, force_deps = force_deps, quiet = quiet,     ..., out_dir = out_dir, skip_if_log_exists = skip_if_log_exists)
43: install(source, ..., quiet = quiet, metadata = metadata, out_dir = out_dir,     skip_if_log_exists = skip_if_log_exists)
44: install_remote(..., quiet = quiet)
45: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
46: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
47: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
48: tryCatch(install_remote(..., quiet = quiet), error = function(e) {    if (!quiet) {        message("Installation failed: ", conditionMessage(e))    }    FALSE})
49: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
50: vapply(remotes, try_install_remote, ..., FUN.VALUE = logical(1))
51: install_remotes(remotes, quiet = quiet, ...)
52: devtools::install_github("IRkernel/IRkernel")

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

What is this segmentation fault? What does it mean that the 'memory' is 'not mapped'?

Comment: maybe try the authors' suggestion here: https://irkernel.github.io/installation/ ?

Comment: install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'evaluate', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 'devtools', 'uuid', 'digest')) gives me the following error: "installation of package ‘evaluate’ had non-zero exit status". So it seems that I cannot install the package 'evaluate'. Is 'evaluate' a dependency of IRkernel?

Comment: based on DESCRIPTION (https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/blob/master/DESCRIPTION), yes, `evaluate` is a required package